# Three.js CanvasRender problems: faces flicker in and out

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, three.js

I am drawing two relative simple shapes and the geometry of them do not overlap.

Here is the code sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/pGD4n/9/

The Three.js Trackball is in there so you can click and drag to spin the objects around in 3d space. The problem is that as the objects rotate some faces disappear revealing the object below. A slight more rotation and the missing face returns, but others have gone missing.

I've tried BasicMaterial, Normal Material and LambertMaterial with both SmoothShading and Flat Shading. I have tried the scene with and without lighting. Moving the objects farther apart seems to correct the issue, but in the given example code the meshes do not overlap and should not have this problem. Problem happens in both Chrome and Firefox.

I imagine that switching to the OpenGL renderer would resolve the issue, but for compatibility we need use the Canvas renderer.

Any help or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a limitation of `CanvasRenderer`. Unfortunately per pixel z sorting is not available in `CanvasRenderer` so it basically tries to sort the whole polygon instead. Depending of where you're looking from the center of one polygon may be closer than the polygon on the side and so it "jumps".

The only solution right now is using `WebGLRenderer`. I'm working on a new renderer for context2d which hopefully will solve this without requiring webgl but it will still take some time.

Comment: I totally understand & thanks for the response. It's hard to see in the tiny example, but the edges of each face also show up on the objects created with the Shape() class. They look like a wireframe is overlaid on the object. Any ideas on how to make those go away? Do you think they are coming from Shape() or from the Canvas Renderer? Thanks again for your help, you are so gracious.

Comment: `material.overdraw = true` should get rid of the the `CanvasRenderer` wireframe glitch.

Comment: your solution has worked great! by further sub-dividing the faces we have been able to completely eliminate the problem. though, we are hitting a render limitation based on the machine processor, seems like 4k faces (even if they are transparent) is about all we can push at 50% processing power on top of the line machine. hehe, i hope that makes sense. Your library is really fabulous.

Comment: Yep. `CanvasRenderer` is software based so it's easy to hit the limits there :/